# Parsing MySQL date with moment

Tags: mysql, momentjs

I'm getting a date from MySQL and trying to parse it with moment

```
let date = moment('2017-02-27T00:00:00.000Z').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
console.log(date) //2017-02-26
```

Why am i losing a day; And what is the correct way to parse it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is happening because of Time Zone.

You can change it using `.tz()` to use specific timezone or use `.utc()`

```
let date = moment('2017-02-27T00:00:00.000Z').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
console.log(date) //2017-02-27
```

http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/

Comment: Funny how this answer helped me solving a date-related issue exactly 3 years after the date it was posted. I was using .format('Y-M-d'), according to PHP's specification. Cheers 

Comment: saved my time. You can even add time in the format('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00')